# How to show WebPage in blackberry application?

Tags: blackberry

How can we show the web page in the blackberry application.Pls share ur ideas to show the web page in blackberry application using broswerfield.If possible provide some code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

The best place to look is in the sample code that ships with the JDE itself (or Eclipse plugin).  Specifically, there is a sample app called "BrowserFieldSampleApplication" that has all the sample code you desire.